# Server logs showing weird activity (How to replicate)

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, express, amazon-ec2, server

I've been running a website on an Ubuntu EC2 instance that serves a useful tool that I use on the go (just displaying changing data). Mostly my goal here is to learn server security. The server runs a NodeJS server with Express, kept alive with ForeverJS.

Over the past two weeks I've seen some typical weak tries at "hacking", if you would call it that. For example, requests thrown at "/wp-admin" and "/administrator/manifests/libraries/joomla.xml". Recently though, I've been getting requests that look like this:

```
[0mGET http://robercid.es/ [32m200 [0m1.019 ms - 10669[0m
[0mGET http://api.ipify.org/ [32m200 [0m0.668 ms - 10669[0m
```

It doesn't look like they go through, but I'm curious as to how this is accomplished, and also what the "hacker" is trying to accomplish.

Also, as for security, I think I've covered everything (SSH Keys, non-20 SSH port, all ports except 80 closed), but is there anything specific to route handling that I should do security wise? Any non-valid page gets a 404, inputs are sanitized, DB is limited to local network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its probably not much to worry about. IP addresses in EC2 are part of a big pool and get used by different customers. Sometimes those IP addresses end up hardcoded into applications or are used to resolve cached DNS lookups that are not respecting ttl.

If it becomes a problem, like getting an ip address that was used for a high volume API endpoint, then you can simply stop/start your instance to get a new IP. Or, just request a new elastic ip and assign it to your instance.